# Merge bootstrap css and JS file with our custom css and JS to make a sigle Http connection

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a single  server call for css and JS file for to optimize the speed. So can any one suggest me Is this good to merge  css and JS with our custom css and JS. And also i override Bootstrap css class in custom css It will create any problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, no problem should happen. putting codes and rules in different files is to manage them in better way.

the point is don't forget to place bootstrap css rules above your own rules. this way your customized rules will override bootstraps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [`UglifyCSS`](https://github.com/fmarcia/UglifyCSS) and [`UglifyJS`](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS). You can also use an asset management framework for PHP like [`Assetic`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) that uses these tools easily.

The CSS cascading order is very important, the last declared is more relevant.

Comment: Hi pedro gamez one more thing is the good to merge bootstrap javascrip and our custom javascript with jquery???

Comment: In my HTML5 game I merge JQuery, my custom Javascript and others vendors libraries. It is recommended because you send only an asset :). Of course in the project the files are separated but when they are sent, my project merge all javascript and compress.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely combine them. Just be sure to do so in the same order you would load them if loading separate files.

Afterwards, minify them using any number of minifiers (just google it), and even gzip them for even smaller files.

Assuming you've done the same with your images and icons (i.e. spriting them) you'll have very few http requests.